# extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product

Tags: magento-1.8, rss

I need to extend getPriceHtml method of Mage_Catalog_Block_Products class.

Why?
I need to change template for price only for my custom extension of RSS (Aph_Rss > works fine!). This extension use `getPriceHtlmRss($product,true)` new method, now I want extend `getPriceHtml > getPriceHtmlRss` to add inline css into price-last / special-price tag for email-marketing automation in specific template > `priceRss.phtml`

I've created Aph/Catalog/etc -> config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Aph_Catalog_Block_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then created `Aph/Catalog/Block/Product.php`

```
<?php

include('Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php');

class Aph_Catalog_Block_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product
{
    protected $_finalPrice = array();

    public function getPriceHtmlRss($product)
    {
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/priceRss.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Then created:
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/priceRss.phtml

Last step:
Created file `app/etc/modules/Aph_Catalog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Aph_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Aph_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Visiting `http://www.mydomain.tld/rss/catalog/category/cid/193/store_id/2/` -> no price shown. `priceRss.phtml` not loaded. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have ***rewrite*** `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product`  class properly.

As per as my knowledge ,on `www.mydomain.tld/rss` page  `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product`  ***block  class does not  rendered.***

Basically, `www.mydomain.tld/rss`   page   ***Mage_Rss_Block_List***  rendered.

Please check at `rss.xml` file `for understand the layout of rss page`  at `your theme layout` folder ***app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout***.

Hope you will be understand.

Comment: I think you need some additional information!

Comment: if you have then please add those on question

Comment: I think you need some additional information! These modules (Aph_Rss and Aph_Catalog) allow to create newsletter via RSS by custom CSS for price box. Aph_Rss module render thumbnail 300x300px (default is 75x75px) and use new method getPriceHtmlRss to show price with inline CSS. getPriceHtmlRss is a new method that extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product. Why do that? Because Google and Android Gmail App use a preprocessor to strip HTML / CSS in the body. By that I need to insert inline CSS into html and to do this I've created new template priceRss.phtml

Comment: Kindly. add this info to question thus any user can understand

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems bit unclear for me. However check below points.

1. Your module should be depend upon `Mage_Catalog` module. You can do this via activation file of your module.

   File : `app\etc\modules\Aph_Catalog.xml`

   ```
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Aph_Catalog>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
               <depends>
                   <Mage_Catalog/>
               </depends>
           </Aph_Catalog>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. Make sure your module resides in `local` codepool.ie at `app\code\local`.
3. You said you have a custom extension `Aph_Rss`. By it's name I assume it customized Magento's default RSS Module, ie `Mage_Rss`. You again said you have a problem with `getPriceHtmlRss()` which comes inside the custom extension `Aph_Rss`. If that is the case, you need to overwrite `Aph_Rss` block class not `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` block class. If this is the case, then you need to provide more details on which block class in `Aph_Rss` holds the method `getPriceHtmlRss()` and give more details about that extension.